# Illegal Assignment Error on custom object and query

Tags: apex, remote-action

I am getting an illegal assignment error on my getTotal() method, but I don't understand why it is not an issue with the getVolume() method. Any guesses as to the cause, or how to modify the method?

```
global with sharing class AccountRemoter {
    public String program {get;set;}
    public static Volume__c volume {get; set;}
    public static Volume__c total {get; set;}
    public AccountRemoter(){}


    @RemoteAction 
    global static Volume__c getVolume(String program){
        volume = [SELECT Name, january__c, february__c, march__c, april__c,
                  may__c, june__c, july__c, august__c, september__c, october__c, november__c,
                  december__c FROM Volume__c WHERE Name = :program and year__c = 2017];             
        return volume;
    }   

    @RemoteAction
    global static Volume__c getTotal(){
        total = [SELECT SUM(january__c), SUM(february__c), SUM(march__c), SUM(april__c),
                 SUM(may__c), SUM(june__c), SUM(july__c), SUM(august__c), SUM(september__c),
                 SUM(october__c), SUM(november__c), SUM(december__c) FROM Volume__c 
                 WHERE year__c = 2017];
        return total;
    } 


}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Adding aggregate functions such as `SUM` changes the result of the query to be an array of `AggregateResult` objects. In general, the aggregation might be creating new values such as a `COUNT()` of the records so extra value names are needed. But for your example, if you really wanted to, you could assign the result values back into a `Volume__c` object and return that.

See e.g. [Working with SOQL Aggregate Functions](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_SOQL_agg_fns.htm) for more information.